# How to get abbreviations of the bibliography into the list of shorthands?

Tags: biblatex, acronyms

I wish to build a list of shorthands that also contains  abbreviations used *inside* the bibliography (I am especially thinking of the shortjournal-field).

Consider the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[german]{babel}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Lutzeier1983,
Author = {Peter Rolf Lutzeier},
Journal = {Zeitschrift f{\"u}r Sprachwissenschaft},
Shortjournal = {ZfS},
Pages = {45-71},
Shorttitle = {Wortfelder},
Title = {Wortfelder als Ma{\ss}stab f{\"u}r Interpretationen an Beispielen des Feldes der Stimmungen im Deutschen},
Volume = {2},
Year = {1983},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\cite{Lutzeier1983}

\printshorthands
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

I would like biblatex to build up the list of shorthands *automatically* by using the fields journal and shortjournal. How can I tell biblatex to treat the field shortjournal in a similar way like the field shorthand?

The only possibility I can think of is to *manually* add  an entry like

```
@book{AbkZfS,
Options = {skipbib=true},
Shorthand = {ZfS},
Title = {Zeitschrift f{\"u}r Sprachwissenschaft}}
```

to the bib-file and the command

```
\nocite{AbkZfS}
```

to the tex-file. Is there a more convenient way to get a list of shorthands including a line like "Zfs = Zeitschrift f{\"u}r Sprachwissenschaft"?

Thank you!

Comment: I seem to be adding a lot of comments like "this will be possible in the future" and this appears to be another example ... in biblatex 2.0/biber 1.0 this will be possible as we will allow arbitrary differently sorted "lists" (read bibliographies, shorthand lists etc.) in any refsection. So you could print a "list" which consists of a filtered shorthand list of just these fields. It's not completely clear how the interface will look but the backend part in biber is already implemented.

Comment: @PLK Thanks for keeping us updated. Is there any chance that these lists will be able to draw more than just one item from a single entry?

Comment: Yes, I think we'll aim for a customisable interface. Currently a "list" is either a normal reference list or a shorthands list. I suspect we'll abstract the "shorthand" list type into something more generic so people can construct lists of based on a chosen set of fields. Probably an extension of the biblatex entry filters for printbibliography.

Comment: @PLK: With `biblatex` 2.8a being released, has there been an update to this question?

Comment: Good question. Not yet - it's still "todo". It needs some changes to the biblatex internals.

Comment: This is now possible using the biblatex 2.9/biber 1.9 DEV versions, see answer below.

Answer (score 6):

This is possible since biblatex 2.9/biber 1.9. The whole `\printshorthands` facility was revised and generalised when using biber. All the details are in the PDF manual and there is a new example file (92-bibliographylists.tex) that comes with biblatex. `\printshorthands` is now implemented in terms of this new system. Here is an example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@ARTICLE{test1,
    AUTHOR = {John Smith},
    TITLE = {A Tremendously Interesting Opinion},
    SHORTHAND = {JSTIP},
    SHORTTITLE = {TIP},
    JOURNALTITLE = {Journal of Tremendously Interesting Opinions},
    SHORTJOURNAL = {JTIO},
    VOLUME = {1},
    NUMBER = {1},
    YEAR = {1947}
}
@ARTICLE{test2,
    AUTHOR = {John Tumble},
    TITLE = {A Tremendously Interesting Idea},
    SHORTHAND = {JSTII},
    SHORTTITLE = {TII},
    JOURNALTITLE = {Journal of Tremendously Interesting Ideas},
    SHORTJOURNAL = {JTII},
    VOLUME = {1},
    NUMBER = {1},
    YEAR = {1946}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{shortjournal}{%
  \printfield{journaltitle}}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{shorttitle}{%
  \printfield{title}}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}

\printshorthands% With biber, just an alias for \printbiblist{shorthand}
\printbiblist[title={Journal Shorthands}]{shortjournal}
\printbiblist[title={Title Shorthands}]{shorttitle}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Which results in:

[image]

If you need to make sure any such lists have unique keys, a `bibcheck` is automatically created and named after the list and so if you had multiple entries in the same journal with the same `shortjournaltitle`, you would get duplicate entries and could address this with:

```
\let\sjnames\relax
\defbibcheck{shortjournal}{%
  \xifinlist{\thefield{shortjournal}}\sjnames
    {\skipentry}
    {\listxadd\sjnames{\thefield{shortjournal}}}}
```

Comment: Thanks for adding that functionality! It seems like we can discard the clause about the DEV versions – I can compile your MWE using the current CTAN versions without any problems.

Comment: However, if I have two items from the same journal, and no matter if same or not issue, the shortjournal biblist will give me x-times the same item.

An example of what I mean.

https://it.overleaf.com/project/65d0cfa56405a39fe55f4dac

How to have only one time the shortjournal in the shortjournal list?

Comment: @cicciocontini - see updated answer - `biblatex` automatically adds a `bibcheck` named after the list and you can use this to remove duplicates for any list that might have them.

Answer (score 5):

Considering PLK's comment, here is a workaround you can use in the meantime. Unfortunately shorthands for journal titles will still need to be specified as separate entries (of the type `customa`), but it takes care of invoking `\nocite` for you.

The solution also allows you to omit `journaltitle` in `article` entries with a `shortjournal` field. The long title can be recovered using `\entrydata`. This is demonstrated below with Muller's article.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,sorting=nty]{biblatex}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{customa}{%
  \printfield{title}%
  \nopunct}

\AtEveryCitekey{%
  \iffieldundef{shortjournal}
    {}
    {\nocite{\thefield{shortjournal}}}}

\renewbibmacro*{journal}{%
  \iffieldundef{shortjournal}
    {\iffieldundef{journaltitle}
       {}
       {\printtext[journaltitle]{%
          \printfield[titlecase]{journaltitle}%
          \setunit{\subtitlepunct}%
         \printfield[titlecase]{journalsubtitle}}}}
    {\printfield{shortjournal}}}

\newbibmacro*{journal:long}{%
  \iffieldundef{journaltitle}
    {\iffieldundef{shortjournal}
       {}
       {\entrydata{\thefield{shortjournal}}
          {\printtext[journaltitle]{\printfield[titlecase]{title}}}}}
    {\printtext[journaltitle]{\printfield[titlecase]{journaltitle}}}}

\AtBeginShorthands{%
  \renewbibmacro*{journal}{\usebibmacro{journal:long}}}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@customa{WMQ,
  Shorthand = {WMQ},
  Title = {William and Mary Quarterly}}
@customa{ZfS,
  Shorthand = {ZfS},
  Title = {Zeitschrift f{\"u}r Sprachwissenschaft}}
@customa{ZHF,
  Shorthand = {ZHF},
  Title = {Zeitschrift für historische Forschung}}
@article{Muller,
  Author = {J{\"o}rn M{\"u}ller},
  Shorthand = {Ergon},
  Shortjournal = {ZHF},
  Pages = {513-542},
  Title = {Ergon und eudaimonia},
  Volume = {57,4},
  Year = {2003}} 
@book{companion,
  Author = {Goossens, Michel and Mittelbach, Frank and Samarin, Alexander},
  Title = {The LaTeX Companion},
  Edition = {1},
  Publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
  Location = {Reading, Mass.},
  Year = {1994}}
@article{Reese,
  Author = {Reese, Trevor R.},
  Title = {Georgia in Anglo-Spanish Diplomacy, 1736-1739},
  Journaltitle = {William and Mary Quarterly},
  Shortjournal = {WMQ},
  Volume = {15},
  Series = {3},
  Date = {1958},
  Pages = {168--190}}
@article{Lutzeier,
  Author = {Peter Rolf Lutzeier},
  Shorthand = {PRL},
  Journal = {Zeitschrift f{\"u}r Sprachwissenschaft},
  Shortjournal = {ZfS},
  Pages = {45-71},
  Shorttitle = {Wortfelder},
  Title = {Wortfelder als Ma{\ss}stab f{\"u}r Interpretationen an
    Beispielen des Feldes der Stimmungen im Deutschen},
  Volume = {2},
  Year = {1983}}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{companion,Muller,Lutzeier,Reese}
\printshorthands
\printbibliography[nottype=customa]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution! I have a question concerning it: How would it be possible to exclude all entries from the list of shorthands that *do not* contain the field shorthand? Right now every cited entry appears twice, even those that do not have abbreviations.

Comment: @hubi Whoops. That is an obvious bug. Thanks for catching it. I've updated the solution to include a category that will filter the shorthand list.

Comment: Thank you again, still another question: I want to use the shortjournal-field inside the bibliography, but the journaltitle-field inside the list of shorthands. If I use the following command, biblatex changes every journaltitle-field into the shortjournal-field. Is there a way only to change the biblography?


\AtEveryBibitem{%
   \iffieldundef{shortjournal}{}
   {\savefield{shortjournal}{\temptitle}%
  \restorefield{journaltitle}{\temptitle}}%
  }%

Comment: @hubi That hook will affect titles in both the list of shorthands and the bibliography. A better way might be to edit the `journal` bibliography macro - `authoryear` uses the generic definition found in `biblatex.def`. I've updated my answer to demonstrate this approach.

Comment: (this intended as comment, not as answer, but I dont know how to produce a comment) @Audrey Thanks again! Unfortunately I always detect new troubles while trying to solve my problem. Now there's a problem concerning the sorting of the list of shorthands. I suppose I should really wait for the official biblatex-enhancement, but anyway, consider the following entry: @article{Muller2003, Author = {J{\"o}rn M{\"u}ller}, Journal = {Zeitschrift für historische Forschung}, Shortjournal = {ZHF}, Keywords = {Aristoteles; Werk}, Pages = {513-542}, Subtitle = {Pl{\"a}doyer f{\"u}r eine unifizierende Inte

Comment: @hubi: You session has expired and now you created a second, identical looking account. New user under 50rep can't comment everywhere only to their own questions and the answer to them. I can merge both accounts together, but it would be better if you simply register your account. I or another moderator will convert this answer to a comment after a little while.

Comment: @hubi Well, clearly I was too hasty in answering this question! I don't have time to look into this problem. And given the upcoming `biblatex` features, it probably isn't worthwhile anyway. I'll post a simplified solution. It won't be much better than your "manual" approach, though.