# biblatex: shorthands in Reference section

Tags: biblatex

I'm quite new with `biblatex`.

Is there a possibility to have the shorttitle within the Reference list? I'd like to have something as the normal entries, each looking +/- like

> Jorio Marco, "Wider den Pakt mit dem Teufel". Die Gegenwehr der
>   Konservativen, in: Hildbrand/Tanner, Revolution, S. 139–160. *[Jorio,
>   Pakt]*

I mainly care about the latest part. The "List of Shorthands" didn't really do the trick.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem. In special the relevant `bib` entry.

Answer (score 4):

Your bibliography example doesn't contain any year data, but I'm assuming you're using the `authortitle` style (or one of its variants). Also note that `shorttitle` and `shorthand` are distinctive fields.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=authortitle]{biblatex}

\renewbibmacro*{finentry}{%
  \finentry
  \addspace
  \mkbibemph{\printtext[brackets]{\usebibmacro{cite}}}%
}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Bli74,
  author = {Blinder, Alan S.},
  year = {1974},
  title = {The economics of brushing teeth},
  shorttitle = {Brushing teeth},
  journaltitle = {Journal of Political Economy},
  volume = {82},
  number = {4},
  pages = {887--891},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\textheight=120pt% just for the example

\begin{document}

Some text \autocite{Bli74}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If you wish to add lists of shorttitles, biblatex 2.9/biber 1.9 (currently in DEV) can now print arbitrary lists of such information - a generalisation of the `\printshorthands` facility. See my answer to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29122/how-to-get-abbreviations-of-the-bibliography-into-the-list-of-shorthands