# Biber and \printbiblist{shorttitle}: a problem with filters and shortened bibliographical descriptions

Tags: biblatex, biber, acronyms

My question is related to this discussion:
[How to get abbreviations of the bibliography into the list of shorthands?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29122/how-to-get-abbreviations-of-the-bibliography-into-the-list-of-shorthands)

Please take this code into consideration:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@ARTICLE{test1,
    AUTHOR = {John Smith},
    TITLE = {A Tremendously Interesting Opinion},
    SHORTTITLE = {TIP},
    JOURNALTITLE = {Journal of Tremendously Interesting Opinions},
    SHORTJOURNAL = {JTIO},
    VOLUME = {1},
    NUMBER = {1},
    YEAR = {1950},
    KEYWORDS = {important},
}
@ARTICLE{test2,
    AUTHOR = {John Tumble},
    TITLE = {A Tremendously Interesting Idea},
    SHORTTITLE = {ABITLONGERSHORTTITLE},
    JOURNALTITLE = {Journal of Tremendously Interesting Ideas},
    VOLUME = {1},
    NUMBER = {1},
    YEAR = {1960},
}
@BOOK{book1,
    AUTHOR = {Peter Johnson},
    TITLE = {A Tremendously Interesting Title of Book One},
    SHORTTITLE = {ATIT},
    TRANSLATOR = {John Smith},
    ORIGLANGUAGE = {german},
    VOLUME = {1},
    LOCATION = {London},
    PUBLISHER = {Publisher},
    YEAR = {1950},
    KEYWORDS = {important},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}

%\printbiblist[title={Abbreviations}]{shorttitle}
\printbiblist[title={Abbreviations of Important Publications},keyword=important]{shorttitle}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

which produces this:

[image]

My questions:

1. Is it possible to tell biber's `\printbiblist`  to print the
   complete bibliographical descriptions in the abbreviations list (equal to those under "References"), not the shortened versions?
2. As you can see, there is a big white space in the table between
   abbreviations and bibliographical descriptions. This is because of
   article `test2`, which has a longer `SHORTTITLE`. Obviously the filter
   is applied *after* processing the biblist. Is it possible to avoid
   this behaviour, and to format the table according to the actually displayed abbreviations?

Thank you!

Comment: Re no 1: `\DeclareBibliographyDriver{shorttitle}{\usedriver{}{\thefield{entrytype}}\finentry}`.

Comment: Yes, it is possible to do number 2. But it's a bit of a pain. I did something list for printing a list of abbreviations in `biblatex-sbl`. I'll see if I can come up with something minimal for you.

Answer (score 4):

**No. 1** can be addressed quite quickly with

```
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{shorttitle}{\usedriver{}{\thefiel‌​d{entrytype}}\finent‌​ry}
```

**No. 2** can be resolved with the `locallabelwidth` option (new in `biblatex` 3.11). If the option is set to `true` only the entries in the current bibliography (list) are used to determine the label width.

```
\printbiblist[title={Abbreviations of Important Publications}, keyword=important, locallabelwidth]{shorttitle}
```

Then gives the desired output.

Answer (score 1):

OK. I realise I didn't do this in `biblatex-sbl` (I wanted a combined list of abbreviations from a number of fields.) But I think I still found a solution to your problem by modifying a couple of macros from `biblatex`'s internals. I don't think there will be any side effects, but it's fairly specific to your question, rather than being generic. Try this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@ARTICLE{test1,
    AUTHOR = {John Smith},
    TITLE = {A Tremendously Interesting Opinion},
    SHORTTITLE = {TIP},
    JOURNALTITLE = {Journal of Tremendously Interesting Opinions},
    SHORTJOURNAL = {JTIO},
    VOLUME = {1},
    NUMBER = {1},
    YEAR = {1950},
    KEYWORDS = {important},
}
@ARTICLE{test2,
    AUTHOR = {John Tumble},
    TITLE = {A Tremendously Interesting Idea},
    SHORTTITLE = {ABITLONGERSHORTTITLE},
    JOURNALTITLE = {Journal of Tremendously Interesting Ideas},
    VOLUME = {1},
    NUMBER = {1},
    YEAR = {1960},
}
@BOOK{book1,
    AUTHOR = {Peter Johnson},
    TITLE = {A Tremendously Interesting Title of Book One},
    SHORTTITLE = {ATIT},
    TRANSLATOR = {John Smith},
    ORIGLANGUAGE = {german},
    VOLUME = {1},
    LOCATION = {London},
    PUBLISHER = {Publisher},
    YEAR = {1950},
    KEYWORDS = {important},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\pagestyle{empty}

% Print complete bibliographic information in list of abbreviations
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{shorttitle}{\usedriver{}{\thefield{entrytype}}\finentry}

\makeatletter
% Make new importantlabelwidth lengths
\def\do#1{\expandafter\newlength\expandafter{\csname important#1width\endcsname}}
\abx@dolabelfields

% Redefine \blx@bbl@labelfields to also calculate important widths
\def\blx@bbl@labelfields{%
  \def\do##1{%
    \ifcsundef{abx@field@##1}
      {}
      {% calculate label widths
       \blx@setlabwidth{\csname ##1width\endcsname}{%
         \csuse{abx@ffd@*@##1width}{\csname abx@field@##1\endcsname}}%
       % calculate important label widths
       \ifkeyword{important}
         {\blx@setlabwidth{\csname important##1width\endcsname}{%
           \csuse{abx@ffd@*@important##1width}{\csname abx@field@##1\endcsname}}}
         {}}}%
  \abx@dolabelfields}
\makeatother

% New bibliography environment to print the important shorttitles
% This is modified from the standard shorthand bibenvironment
\defbibenvironment{importantshorttitle}
  {\list
     {\printfield[shorthandwidth]{shorttitle}}
     {\setlength{\labelwidth}{\importantshorttitlewidth}%
      \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
      \setlength{\labelsep}{\biblabelsep}%
      \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}%
      \renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{##1\hss}}}
  {\endlist}
  {\item}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}

\printbiblist[title={Abbreviations}]{shorttitle}
\printbiblist[title={Abbreviations of Important
Publications},keyword=important,env=importantshorttitle]{shorttitle}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE]