# Reset \shorthandwidth at \newrefsection

Tags: spacing, biblatex, shorthands

<s>**Edit** Found the answer, see below.</s>

**Edit 2** Unfortunately, my solution to invoke `\setlength{\shorthandwidth}{0pt}` directly after `\newrefsection` does not work as expected – it just sets `\shorthandwidth`to 0 for the whole document.

---

I am currently typesetting a book with several refsections. Unfortunately, biblatex seems to calculate `\shorthandwidth` once for the whole document which leads to hilariously large gaps between the shorthand-label and the bibliographical entry in some of the shorthands-sections of the document (see image).

Is it possible to reset `\shorthandwidth` at `\newrefsection` and make biblatex recalculate `\shorthandwidth` for each refsection?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents*}{problematic.bib}
  @book{short,
    author = {Knuth, Donald E.},
    year = {1986},
    title = {The \TeX book},
    shorthand = {TTB}
  }

  @book{long,
    author = {Atkins, Tom},
    year = {2016},
    title = {Problematically Long Shorthands},
    shorthand = {PrblmtcllLngShrthnds}
  }
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{problematic.bib}

\begin{document}

Text. \cite{long}

\printshorthands

\newrefsection

Text. \cite{short}

\printshorthands

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hmmm. Interesting. I feel like this is something that should just work. I came up with a solution to a similar question here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/349875/biber-and-printbiblistshorttitle-a-problem-with-filters-and-shortened-biblio But I think a more generic one would be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for your example … but I have to confess that I have no idea why. I basically stumbled across it by accident while trying to get different values of the `\shorthandwidth` for each `refsection`.

Given this, make sure you check for unwanted side effects carefully.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{short,
  author = {Knuth, Donald E.},
  year = {1986},
  title = {The \TeX book},
  shorthand = {TTB}
}
@book{long,
  author = {Atkins, Tom},
  year = {2016},
  title = {Problematically Long Shorthands},
  shorthand = {PrblmtcllLngShrthnds}
}
@book{mid,
  author = {Author, Some},
  year = {2016},
  title = {Mid length Shorthands},
  shorthand = {MLShrthnds}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\pagestyle{empty}

\makeatletter
\def\blx@bbl@labelfields{%
  \def\do##1{%
    \ifcsundef{abx@field@##1}
      {}
      {\ifcsundef{##1@\the\c@refsection @width}
         {\expandafter\newlength\expandafter{\csname ##1@\the\c@refsection
          @width\endcsname}}
         {}%
       \blx@setlabwidth{\csname ##1@\the\c@refsection @width\endcsname}{%
         \csuse{abx@ffd@*@##1@\the\c@refsection @width}{%
         \csname abx@field@##1\endcsname}}}}%
  \abx@dolabelfields}

\defbibenvironment{shorthand}
  {\list
     {\printfield[shorthandwidth]{shorthand}}
     {\setlength{\labelwidth}{%
        \csname shorthand@\the\c@refsection @width\endcsname}%
      \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
      \setlength{\labelsep}{\biblabelsep}%
      \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}%
      \renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{##1\hss}}}
  {\endlist}
  {\item}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Text. \cite{short}

\printshorthands

\newrefsection

Text. \cite{long}
Text. \cite{mid}

\printshorthands

\newrefsection

Text. \cite{short}
Text. \cite{mid}

\printshorthands

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. So far I didn't stumble accross any side effects.